# Update Datetime Values in all the Tables in the database

Tags: performance, t-sql, datetime, sql-update, sql-server-2012

How can I update all the tables which have Datetime fields in a database?

Eg. My DB has 50 Tables which has a column in the 50 tables which is of DATETIME Type.
I need to update the Column of datetime type with a new value.

How can I write a generic query to update datetime column in all the tables in the DB with a new value of datetime?

Comment: What on earth could possibly be the benefit of having 50 different columns in your database where every single column and every single row has the same value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I question the value of this in an unprecedented way (you should be proud!), you can't write a generic query that does this without dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE 
  @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'', 
  @newDateTime DATETIME = '20131217 07:30';

SELECT @sql += N'
   UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) 
     + ' SET ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' = @newDateTime;'
FROM sys.columns AS c 
 INNER JOIN sys.tables  AS t ON c.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
 INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
 WHERE c.system_type_id = 61;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@newDateTime DATETIME', @newDateTime;
```

Comment: Tqs a LOT.. Its Working :)